# Enabling buttons upon text/combo box property modifications

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I have 2 different views, `MainView` and `SectionView`, where `SectionView` is a region (using the `prism` library) within `MainView`. In `MainView`, I have a `DataGrid` with `Object`s, each containing 5 properties. 1 of these `Object`s can be selected at a time, which will open the `SelectionView` containing 4 `TextBox`es and 1 `ComboBox` showing the value of the `Object`'s properties. I did this by binding each `TextBox`' `Text="{Binding this.MainView.SelectedObject.[PropertyGoesHere]}"`
Now when one of these properties will be modified, I want two buttons to enable, one to save the changes (which I don't want to save rightaway, so TwoWay is not an option), and one to revert the changes (in other words, reset the values of the boxes to what they were when the user selected the object in the `MainView`).

What I think should be the process is something along the lines of

### Step 1

User selects an `Object` and `MainView.SelectedObject` is set. `SectionView` needs to 'hear' this, and save the property values in it's own `SelectedObject`. The boxes in `SectionView` will show the values of these properties by binding to the `MainView.SelectedObject` properties or get a default value from `SectionView.SelectedObject` (I think the latter would be better?).

### Step 2

By default, the buttons are enabled. Upon modifying one of the properties, both buttons should enable and both Views `.SelectedObject`'s properties should not change. The user now has the choice to press either save or revert. Upon saving, the box' properties should be sent to the `MainView.SelectedObject` (and thus effectively changing the `Object`'s properties) and the buttons should disable again. Upon reverting, the box' properties should be reset to `SectionView.SelectedObject`'s properties and the buttons should disable (and thus giving the user the choice to start over) again.

The reason I don't want anything to work with `Mode="TwoWay"` is because the user may just select another `Object` from the `DataGrid` which should give the same effect as presseing Revert, just with new property values going into the boxes.

### What I did accomplish so far;

I have all independent objects that need to communicate with eachother set up. The views, the `DataGrid` and `TextBox`/`ComboBox`, both the fields to hold the `Object`s in. I can have the boxes in `SectionView` bind to the properties of `MainView.SelectedObject`, but I think this is not how it would work best.

### What I need help with;

The main parts I need help with is setting up the 'hearing' of the `SectionView` to set it's own `.SelectedObject` whenever the `MainView.SelectedObject` is set and enabling the buttons when the properties whitin the boxes are modified.

EDIT: in an attempt to more clearly isolate the problems I have;
I need to have an Object in ViewModel 1 to send it's properties to ViewModel 2.
I need to have 2 buttons enable and disable when the text values of a couple of textboxes are different from their (dynamic) 'default' values.

Comment: Is SectionView a child of MainView or a sibling, or what? If a child, sounds like you want `<local:SectionView SelectedObject="{Binding SelectedObject, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainView}}} ... />` Or maybe `AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}`, if that's what MainView inherits from.

Comment: ...but if it really is a requirement that `SectionView` must have its own copy that "mirrors" `MainView`'s copy, you could bind `SelectedObject`'s properties individually, or slip in a copy in `SectionView.SelectedObject`'s CoerceValue handler. I'm assuming these are both dependency properties; if not, they need to be.

Comment: @EdPlunkett by including the `MainView` as a dependency in the `SectionView` I sort of recreated a parent-child relationship where the child knows of the parent's existence and it's properties, but not vice versa. That's why I'm having issues to set the child's properties when the parent's properties are set. The parent doesn't know what property (or even class, for that matter) to write to.

Comment: If I were for some reason unable to do this with binding, I would be far more comfortable with the parent knowing about the child than vice versa. It's often appropriate for a parent to know about its children, but you want to make a child usable by arbitrary parents whenever possible. But you haven't explained why binding is out of the question.

Comment: @EdPlunkett binding is not out of the question per se, it's just that I need a 'back-up' so to speak. Afaik when I use binding with OneWay I can change the value in the textbox, but not retrieve it from the textbox. When I use TwoWay, it will alter the properties of the object bound and thus not letting me have my default values to revert to. I could be wrong about all that though, as I've tried a couple of different things and can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Hm, I think I see. The way to handle change-reversion is generally to keep a whole backup copy of the edited object. When SelectedObject changes in MainView, you might want it to expose a copy as EditingObject or something, and bind SectionView.SelectedObject to that. Or maybe better, when SectionView gets a new SelectedObject, it makes its own EditingObject copy and edits that. Makes sense for me for SectionView to own the "CancelChanges" command, which would replace EditingObject with a new copy of SelectedObject. ...

Comment: ...and MainView gives SectionView a SaveSelectedObjectCommand with a parameter. That's a property of type ICommand that SectionView exposes and MainView binds a command to. So SectionView is a "Thing Editor" which is given a thing, edits it, reverts changes, edits again, etc., and then when user clicks "Save" in SectionView, SectionView hands off its EditingObject to some arbitrary opaque piece of code that its owner uses to save the thing. MainView then updates the copy in the list, and updates its own SelectedObject, which the binding drives back to SectionView.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Exactly! So my problem is that I can't instantiate the `EditingObject` in `SectionView`, because that should happen when the user selects an `Object` in `MainView.DataGrid` and I don't know how to do that. I'll edit my main post to isolate my problems more clearly.

Comment: Excellent. I don't brain real good at too high a level of abstraction, more concrete details is a big help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123004/discussion-between-ciphra-and-ed-plunkett).

Comment: @EdPlunkett I figured the post would become a little too clunky if I'd start to add code from 4 different classes too..